# Is there a nice way to pad an Integer with zeroes without converting it to a String?

Tags: java, string, format, int

I can't think of a better way to left pad an integer with zeroes without first converting it to a String. Is there a way to do this? I've found numerous questions regarding this but they all require a String conversion. I understand we can find the length with this approach:

```
int length = (num==0) ? 1 : (int)Math.log10(num) + 1;
```

However, this will still require me to convert it to a String and back afterwards. Surely, there's a better way?

Comment: What would it mean to 'left pad'. It means nothing in terms of the integer (since unchanged); it's only applicable to a visual (text) representation of an integer. When you print an integer, it is converted to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. An `int` represents a mathematical integer value, represented as 32 bits. The number 0001 is 1, and has a unique binary representation. Left-padded integers are not integers. they are Strings.

Answer (score 1):

No. Numeric types cannot contain leading zeros. This a feature of the formatted textual representation i.e. `Strings`

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the length I'm guessing the leading zero's are simply for output, but ultimately your question was answered by the other two posters.

```
int length = (num==0) ? 1 : (int)Math.log10(num) + 1;
String zeros;
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
  zeros = zeros.concat("0");
}
System.out.println(zeros + num);
```